# Proving There Exists a Quadratic Function that Shares Tangent Lines With Another Quadratic

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-verification, proof-writing

I have been working on proving a theorem and I think I have it, I'm still new to proofs so any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Theorem:

Let $f(x) = Ax^{2}+Bx+C_{1}$.

Let $y_{1}(x) = f'(Q)x+b$ the tangent line to $f$ at $Q$.

Let $y_{2}(x) = f'(-Q)x+b$ the tangent line to $f$ at $-Q$.

Then there exists a function $g(x) = -Ax^{2}+Bx+C_{2}$ that shares tangent lines $y_1$ and $y_2$ at points $(-Q, f(-Q))$ and $(Q, f(Q))$ with $f$.

Furthermore the value $C_{2}$ on $g(x)$ can be defined:

$\quad C_{2} = C_{1}-2AQ^{2}$

Proof Part 1:

Suppose $y_{1}$ and $y_{2}$ will both have a $y$-intercept of $b$.

$\quad y_{1}(0) = b \quad \wedge \quad y_{2}(0) = b$

Then one can sub the known points into the appropriate functions,

$(Q, f(Q))$ into $y_{1}$:

$\quad AQ^{2}+BQ+C_{1} = 2AQ^2+BQ+b$

Isolate b:

$\quad -AQ^{2}+C_{1} = b$

Carry out the same for $(-Q, f(-Q))$ into $y_{2}$:

$\quad AQ^2 - BQ + C = 2AQ - BQ + b$

$\quad -AQ^2 + C = b$

Therefore $y_{1}$ and $y_{2}$  will always meet at $b$ on the $y$-axis.

Proof Part 2:

Let $g(x) = -Ax^2+Bx+C_{2}$

Let $y_{3}(x) = g'(Q)x+b$ the tangent line to $g$ at $Q$.

Let $y_{4}(x) = g'(-Q)x+b$ the tangent line to $g$ at $-Q$.

Now like before sub in the known points into the appropriate functions.

$(Q, g(Q))$ into $y_{3}$:

$\quad AQ^2+C_{2} = b$

The result is the same for $(-Q, g(-Q))$ into $y_{4}$ which implies $y_{1} = y_{4}$ and $y_{2} = y_{3}$.

Solve for $C_{2}$ to find the vertical translation of $g(x)$:

$\quad C_{2} = b-AQ^{2}$

$\quad C_{2} = (-AQ^2+C_{1})-AQ^{2}$

$\quad C_{2} = -2AQ^{2} + C_{1}$

Therefore given any function $f(x) = Ax^{2}+Bx+C_{1}$ and two tangent lines at $f(Q)$ and $f(-Q)$ then you can find a function $g(x) = Ax^{2}+Bx+(C_{1}-2AQ^{2})$.

Q.E.D

I know it's a long proof but if you can give me any advice I'd really appreciate it. I hope to generalize it some more to see whether or not it would work for any two tangent lines on $f$. Thanks.

Comment: Part 1: You are proving $y$ intercepts are $b$ after "assuming" that it is true? Am I missing something?

Comment: As a starting point, "shares" isn't strict mathematical terminology. Try rewrite the statement of the theorem without using it as it is a bit unclear what you are saying.

Comment: Part 1 starts by the assumption that the two tangent lines share the same y-intercept and tries to prove that it is true

Comment: When you prove something, you can't assume that it is true first and then prove that it is true. That is called a circular argument. 

I think you are trying to say that you are "constructing" a tangent line of a parabola which is equal to the tangent line of another parabola in order to show that you can always do this. Is this correct?

Comment: Yeah I want to show that with two tangent lines at Q and -Q on f that you can make a second function g that has the same tangent lines and is just vertically reflected and translated by $-2AQ^2+C_{1}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest, I find your proof of this a little confusing. I think this comes down to the fact that you haven't stated *exactly* what you are trying to prove. What you mean quadratic functions "sharing" a tangent line can be stated more precisely as:

If $f(x)=Ax^2+Bx+C$ then for any $c\in\Bbb R$ there is a function $g(x)=Dx^2+Ex+F$ distinct from $f$ such that $f'(c)=g'(c)$, $f(c)=g(c)$ and $f'(-c)=g'(-c)$,$f(-c)=g(-c)$

Since the value of a function and its derivative at its point completely determine its tangent lines, it follows that the tangent to $f$ at $c$ is equal to the tangent to $g$ at $c$.

To go from here, you just need to find $E,D,F$ which will work. You get two equations which they must satisfy:

$$f(c)=Ac^2+Bc+C=Dc^2+Ec+F=g(c)$$
$$f'(c)=2Ac+B=2Dc+E=g'(c)$$

I rearranged these equations to get $E=2Ac^2-2Dc^2+B$ and $F=Dc^2-Ac^2+C$ so if the tangent lines agree at $c$ then:

$$g(x)=Dx^2+Ex+F=Dx^2 + (2Ac^2-2Dc^2+B)x+(Dc^2-Ac^2+C)$$

In order for the tangent lines to agree at $-c$ you need to have

$$f(-c)=Ac^2-Bc+C=Dc^2 - (2Ac^2-2Dc^2+B)c+(Dc^2-Ac^2+C)$$

You can rearrange this to find the required value of $D$ so you have explicitly constructed a unique function which satisfies the requirements. The last thing to prove is that it is distinct from $f$

It takes alot of practice, but it is usually easier (especially once you get used to it!) to write proofs if you work as closely as you can with the definitions and keep things as general as possible.

Comment: What I am trying to show is that if you have two tangent lines (one at $f(Q) $ the other at $f(-Q)$ then there will be another quadratic function $g(x)$ that has the same tangent lines at $g(Q)$ and $g(-Q)$. Graphically $g(x)$ will be underneath the intersection of the two tangent lines and vertically reflected over the $x$-axis relative to $f$. Maybe I am reading your answer wrong but it looks to me like this a proof for only one tangent line.

Comment: You are right. Ill update the answer.